# Squid fails to block Facebook

Tags: centos, proxy, squid

I have squid proxy server running on Centos 8 its failed to block any https site.

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
#acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255 # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8        # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10     # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
#acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16    # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16        # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src fc00::/7          # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10         # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl localnet src 200.200.200.0/24
http_access allow localnet

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#badsite block
#acl badsite url_regex "/etc/squid/block"
#http_access deny badsite 
acl badsite dstdomain .facebook.com
http_access deny badsite

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete or comment out the very first `http_access allow localnet` immediately after the `acl localnet src 200.200.200.0/24` line.

The way you've written your config file, that allow rule comes before every other allow or deny rule, so they never even get a chance: localnet is allowed to access everything without any restriction.

That's why, in the sample squid.conf that you've edited, the `http_access allow localnet` comes after almost all the other allow/deny rules and immediately before the `http_access deny all` rule.

Comment: BTW, you probably want to add `fbcdn.net` to your `badsite` acl.

Comment: Thank you for your support.it worked.

Comment: I have an other question to ask i have blocked some sites through squid when anyone access to blocked url it simply show the page browser cant open the page. I just want to redirect URL to squid default Error page for blocked site I hope you understand what im trying to explain. Please advice necessary .

Comment: There are a few ways that squid can do that, but if you have a new question, you should post a new question.  this site runs on questions and answers, and both asking and answering questions in comments is frowned upon.

Comment: i have already posted this question until now didn't get response.